# How to insert text in multiple files using python

Tags: python-3.x

I'm working on some formatting some pay slips. The .txt file that I exported doesn't have any headers. I've solved that part by using the .insert() method. I have also worked out how to split the large file so that every pay slip is an individual file. 
What I'm trying to do now is to open all of the .txt files in the directory and then run the .insert() script so that all of the files get headers and then save the files to the same directory.

It's probably pretty obvious but I'm a beginner...I have spent quite a number of hours on this though. 
I'd really appreciate some pointers.

I have tried a few different approaches. The last I've tried is this.

```
import glob

for file in glob.glob('./*txt'):
    with open(file.replace('.txt', '-out.txt'), 'w') as outfile
        with open(file) as infile:
            for contents in infile:
                 outfile.write(contents.insert(1,'header'))
                 outfile.write(contents.insert(3,'header2'))
        outfile = ''.join(contents)
    infile.close()
    outfile.close()
```

I most often get this error

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'insert'

Comment: A few code review things before I try to answer the question: 1. You don't need to close the files explicitly, as the `open` context manager will automatically close them for you, and 2. you can nest your context managers: `with open(...) as infile, open(...) as outfile`.

Comment: What do you mean by "headers"? You're getting the error because `contents` doesn't have an `.insert()` method defined, as `contents` is a `str` (string).

Comment: What do you want achieve with `.insert()`? Do you want insert the headers in line 1 and 3 of the new file? In your for loop you would add the headers at position 1 and 3 in every line of your output file, if insert would work on strings.

Comment: Thomas: Thank you for the tips. By headers in mean inserting a string of text above certain lines to give context to the information when it is printed out. I probably used terminology wrongly in my question.

Comment: Olupo: Yes, I want to add text to line 1 and 3. Thank you very much for your help, you made my friday

Comment: @The_wix Did my comment or my answer help you?

Comment: @Olupo your answer helped me a lot. I could see right away what I did wrong. I tried to upvote your answer but I don't have enough reputation yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert the content of `infile` to a list which contains every line as separate string with `infile.readlines()`. Then you can insert your strings as list elements at the desired positions. At last you join the strings in the list to one string and write it in `outfile`.

```
import glob

for file in glob.glob('./*txt'):
    with open(file.replace('.txt', '-out.txt'), 'w') as outfile:
        with open(file) as infile:
            text = infile.readlines()
            text.insert(1, "header\n")
            text.insert(3, "header2\n")

            outfile.write(''.join(text))
```